# DNS error only in IE

Tags: domain-name-system, internet-explorer, internal-dns, intranet

Our Intranet page has stopped working on some machines/some user accounts. The error I am getting points to a DNS issue but If I ping the site from the command line the it responds fine.

The error I'm gettting on IE is

```
Error: The web filter could not find the address for the requested site
Why are you seeing this:
The system is unable too determine the IP address of intranet.example.com
```

I'm not quite sure why it mentions the web filter as there is a proxy exception for the intranet page and if I run a trace route it doesn't go via the web proxy (filtering system).

Finally it isn't affecting everyone, just random users, also it doesn't affect the random users on all the client machines they use. I have one user where it happens on any client they log onto where most its just certian clients. It's even "fixed" itself for a few peoples.

EDIT: hey Mikey thanks for the fast response. Proxies are correct and automatic configuration is off (both via GPO)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you have an incorrect proxy set in your Internet Options (which ties into IE and some windows functions.. but most significantly *not* the command line or most other browsers).

Some malware is known to do this. Might be a good ideal to double check the options.

Make sure you have "automatic configuration" turned off in there as well, unless you use that function.